# Why are these navbar links overflowing on top of section outside the header?

Tags: css, header, navbar, positioning, hamburger-menu

I am trying to get the links on the navbar to take full width and NOT take any of the area of the background image placed on the following section when the page is displayed on a smaller viewport `@media (max-width: 900px)`.

Why is the hamburger menu icon not displaying?

I am trying to get navmenu items stacked and then a background image to display in full on a smaller viewport.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: var(--secondary-dark);
  color: var(--main-white);
  padding: 5px 30px;
  height: 90px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: var(--fs-600);
  margin: 0.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: var(--ff-nav);
  font-weight: var(--fw-400);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar-items ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-items li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--main-white);
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-items li:hover a {
  color: var(--blue-primary);
}

.toggle-button a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button a .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-white);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar-items {
    /* display: none; */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--secondary-dark);
  }

  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-items ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-items li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-items li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    width: 100;
  }

  .navbar-items.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}


/* //////////////////////
      Main 
/////////////////////// */

.welcome {
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  padding-top: 70px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url("/img/background.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.welcome p {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: var(--clr-section-background);
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <span>Brand</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-items">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#services">Services</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<!--mission statement------------------------------------------>

<section class="welcome">
  <div>
    <p>#OnPoint</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, I just needed to add a z-index on navbar and remove padding on ul in order to have the hamburger menu displaying on full width on smaller viewports.